# precaching a generated asset in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, aem, service-worker, offline-caching

I have some resources which are getting generated on runtime or on build for example scripts, CSS, etc.
The file format is something like this `main.min.63716273681.js` and similarly for other resources as well.

Unfortunately, I cannot use *sw-precache* library or anything integrated with my build.

How can I precache those resources, Is it possible to do it using regex?

*Note: The question is about precaching the resource and resources are getting generated by AEM(Adobe experience manager)*

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the problem that you don't know the exact names of the files you want to cache? In that case it's not possible to help you without more info about your build system. Otherwise just use [toolbox.precache(arrayOfURLs)](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/api.html#toolboxprecachearrayofurls)

Comment: Yes, I do not know the number which is getting generated after every build.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install webpack-manifest-plugin and import at the top of your webpack config file

```
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
```

use the below code in your webpack plugin section this will generate a file name asset-manifest.json with all the assets that are build by webpack

```
new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: your public path here,
 }),
```

it will generate file having content like below

// asset-manifest.json

```
{
  "files": {
    "about.js": "/static/js/about.bc816d03.chunk.js",
    "about.js.map": "/static/js/about.bc816d03.chunk.js.map",
    "dashboard.js": "/static/js/dashboard.f180c270.chunk.js",
    "dashboard.js.map": "/static/js/dashboard.f180c270.chunk.js.map",
    "homepage.js": "/static/js/homepage.4dd0316c.chunk.js",
    "homepage.js.map": "/static/js/homepage.4dd0316c.chunk.js.map",
    "login.js": "/static/js/login.1b8cf466.chunk.js",
    "login.js.map": "/static/js/login.1b8cf466.chunk.js.map",
    "logout.js": "/static/js/logout.ac3c5758.chunk.js",
    "logout.js.map": "/static/js/logout.ac3c5758.chunk.js.map",
    "main.css": "/static/css/main.977b6895.chunk.css",
    "main.js": "/static/js/main.a65a1d5d.chunk.js",
    "main.js.map": "/static/js/main.a65a1d5d.chunk.js.map",
    "profile.js": "/static/js/profile.20ae3dae.chunk.js",
    "profile.js.map": "/static/js/profile.20ae3dae.chunk.js.map",
    "runtime-main.js": "/static/js/runtime-main.ad8b0a50.js",
    "runtime-main.js.map": "/static/js/runtime-main.ad8b0a50.js.map",
    "static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js": "/static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js",
    "static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js.map": "/static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js.map",
    "index.html": "/index.html",
    "precache-manifest.e770a629726af82e25b547dd941bae89.js": "/precache-manifest.e770a629726af82e25b547dd941bae89.js",
    "service-worker.js": "/service-worker.js",
    "static/css/main.977b6895.chunk.css.map": "/static/css/main.977b6895.chunk.css.map",
    "static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt": "/static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt",
    "static/media/arvidsson.jpg": "/static/media/arvidsson.4d6f8e0d.jpg",
    "static/media/logo.jpg": "/static/media/logo.8caa15b8.jpg",
    "static/media/pekka.jpg": "/static/media/pekka.1eab475c.jpg"
  },
  "entrypoints": [
    "static/js/runtime-main.ad8b0a50.js",
    "static/js/8.796ce7e3.chunk.js",
    "static/css/main.977b6895.chunk.css",
    "static/js/main.a65a1d5d.chunk.js"
  ]
}
```

you can read `asset-manifest.json` file and take the files object and iterate and check the key having .js in the end.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vipin, I am using AEM and resources(clientlibs) are getting generated by that. I may have migrate to webpack at some point, so this answer is helpful.